# Rails 3 - Issue with storing floats

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, floating-point, migration

I am creating a 3D map and I have the x, y, and z values for each point, the current database I am get the data from has the values like so:

```
x = -8.851079259998058e16
y = 4.236944396687888e16
z = -4.451352534647966e16
```

I have tried to make a database migration like so:

```
class CreateMapPoints < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :map_points do |t|
      t.float :x
      t.float :y
      t.float :z
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

However when I import the data into this new table and run the following in `rails console`, I get strange results:

```
1.9.2-p290 :002 > MapPoint.first
  MapPoint Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `map_points`.* FROM `map_points` LIMIT 1
 => #<MapPoint id: 1, x: -88510800000000000.0, y: 42369400000000000.0, z: -44513500000000000.0, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

The x, y and z are missing the point after the first digit.  Could someone advise on what I am doing incorrect here?  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Tony

Comment: How are you importing the data?

Comment: I am importing it from a CSV file

Comment: And are you doing any `.to_f` calls while importing? You might be sending strings in and letting something else convert them to floats (and make a mess of things along the way).

Comment: yea, i have tried that and it just comes out the same.  doesn't maintain the point.

Comment: I think Eric Postpischil has it right, I didn't see the `e16`s at the end.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from your question what the actual problem is. You say the values are “missing the point after the first digit.” However, the values displayed are approximately the same as the input values. They are just represented differently. The point is a feature of the display format, not a feature of the number. For example, “1/2”, “.5”, and “5e-1” are different representations of the same value. The fact that one has a “/”, one has a “.”, and one has an “e” does not make them different numbers.

-8.851079259998058e16 is approximately the same as -88510800000000000.0. (The “e16” at the end means multiplied by 10<sup>16</sup>.) However, it is different, after the sixth significant digit. So there are questions of whether this difference is real and whether it is a problem.

By whether this difference is real, I mean I wonder whether the string “-88510800000000000.0” is completely displaying the actual value in the computer. It may be that, when formatting for output, only the first six significant digits were displayed. In some software, default output formats may display only a few significant digits, and it may be possible to display more digits with some modifications to the format settings. You may also be able to specify display using exponential format, as you have shown the input values. This would involve the specific software you are using, on which I cannot advise further.

If the value has actually changed, not just the display of it, then you may need to use a more precise type, such as a double-precision binary floating-point type or an extended- or arbitrary-precision decimal type. Again, the availability of alternate types involves the particular software you are using, and I cannot advise further.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set the precision within the migration and if float doesn't work then try decimal:

```
t.decimal :x, :precision => 15
t.decimal :y, :precision => 15
t.decimal :z, :precision => 15
```